# Connect to a server using public IPv4 address in python

Tags: python, sockets, server, ip, client

I'm experimenting with socket server-client communication using python 3 socket module. Just to test if an eventual connection can be made, I've tried to program the simplest scenario possible. Thus the server code has the only purpose to print new connections; its code is:

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(("0.0.0.0", 30000))

while True:
    server.listen()
    print("listening...")
    conn, addr = server.accept()

    print(f"{addr} connected")
```

while the client only tries to connect to the server using the public IPv4 address of my computer:

```
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print("Trying to connect...")
client.connect(("99.99.99.99", 30000))
client.close()
```

When I try to run the server and then the client nothing happens: the server just waits for conections, while the client displays nothing. After a while on the client side it is displayed the socket timeout error. I've tried to establish the connection even running the server and the client on the same computer, I've tried changing the ip of the server to "localhost" or "127.0.0.1", but nothing happens. Have you got any ideas on how this issue can be solved?

P.S. Thank you in advance for eventual answers and excuse my poor English, I'm still practising it!

Comment: use the local ip address (usually starts with `192.168...`, at least on windows use `ipconfig` in cmd to get it), start server on that address and connect to that same address too

Comment: Yes, in that case it works, but my goal is to remotely connect two devices that can also not belong to the same wifi network. Is it possible using public ip?

Comment: yes, possible, you probably need to enable port forwarding tho, somewhere in the router settings, it may also cost sth to the ISP or use some cloud service like https://www.pythonanywhere.com/

Comment: oh, understood, thanks for your time!